# Convert timestamp belonging to a particular timezone into Timestamp for another timezone

Tags: java, java-8

Consider `Timestamp sourceTimestamp` belonging to `Timezone sourceTimezone` . I want to convert `sourceTimestamp` to a new `Timestamp` belonging to `Timezone newTimezone`.
How do I get this new `Timestamp`?

Basically I want a function like

```
Timestamp myFunction(Timestamp sourceTimestamp , Timezone sourceTimezone , Timezone newTimezone){
        ...
        ...
    return newTimestamp
}
```

`Timestamp` belongs to package `java.sql.Timestamp` and `Timezone` belongs to import `java.util.TimeZone`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have to use `java.util`? I'm asking that because there is `java.time` since Java 8, and *java-8* appears in the tags of your question.

Comment: @deHaar I couldn't think of any way. Timestamp belongs to package import java.sql.Timestamp and Timezone belongs to import java.util.TimeZone . The function body can be as per your wish

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `java.sql.Timestamp` for you?

Comment: @devReddit yes it has to be java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

If Java 8 is available to you, you will be best advised to use `java.time`.

Fortunately, a `java.sql.Timestamp` has methods to [convert its values from and to objects/classes from `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--)

You could write a method that takes a `Timestamp` and two `ZoneId`s:

```
public static Timestamp convertZone(Timestamp time, ZoneId originZone, ZoneId targetZone) {
    // create a zone-aware datetime object to fully represent the input
    ZonedDateTime originZdt = time.toLocalDateTime().atZone(originZone);
    /*
     * then change its zone, keeping the epoch millis
     * (only time of day changes according to the zone)
     */
    ZonedDateTime targetZdt = originZdt.withZoneSameInstant(targetZone);
    // and return a Timestamp of the date and time of the adjusted
    return Timestamp.valueOf(targetZdt.toLocalDateTime());
}
```

and then use it somehow like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create some example Timestamp
    Timestamp sourceTimestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
    // define the zones
    ZoneId sourceTimezone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
    ZoneId newTimezone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    // use the method to convert the values
    Timestamp adjusted = convertZone(sourceTimestamp, sourceTimezone, newTimezone);
    // print them
    System.out.println("source: " + sourceTimestamp);
    System.out.println("target: " + adjusted);
}
```

Some moments (`Instant`s ;-) ) ago, the output on my machine was:

```
source: 2021-08-04 08:50:22.913429
target: 2021-08-04 12:20:22.913429
```